# How can I get the S3 location of a Databricks DBFS path

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, databricks, delta-lake, aws-databricks

I know my DBFS path is backed by S3.
Is there any utility/function to get the exact S3 path from a DBFS path?
For example,

```
%python
required_util('dbfs:/user/hive/warehouse/default.db/students')
>> s3://data-lake-bucket-xyz/.......
```

I was going through a few other discussions, for example - [What s3 bucket does DBFS use? How can I get the S3 location of a DBFS path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58240241/what-s3-bucket-does-dbfs-use-how-can-i-get-the-s3-location-of-a-dbfs-path) but didn't get any useful answer

Answer (score 1):

This information isn't really available inside the execution context of the cluster. The closest that I can think about is to use [Account REST API](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/account.html), but you need to be an account admin for that:

- You can get information about specific workspace using [GET Workspace API](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/account.html#operation/get-workspace)
- From result of this GET request, you can get storage configuration ID (the `storage_configuration_id` field), and then use [Get Storage Configuration API](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/account.html#operation/get-storage-config) to retrieve bucket information.

Answer (score 1):

Alex is right regarding the default bucket for a workspace. The following answers may help for more specific versions of this question - the answer for mounts in dbfs is what I was hoping to find here.

**This answer mentions AWS s3 paths, it will apply equally to Azure `adfs:` or GCP `gs:` bucket paths*

#### Database or table location

The question suggests you want to know the location of a database ( `dbfs:/user/hive/warehouse/default.db`) or table within that database (`students`) as opposed to wanting to just know the default bucket.

If the database has been created as a managed database (e.g. with a `location`) then the following may shed light:

```sql
%sql
describe database extended <dbname_here>
```

Unfortunately that won't help for `default` because it will have the location `dbfs:/user/hive/warehouse` **I note this is pre-unity-catalog, we shouldn't be using default anymore*

It might be that you created `students` as an external table, if so then running this may show you an s3 path again if the table is managed in default it will have this location: `dbfs:/user/hive/warehouse/<tablename_here>`

### Mounts

If you are looking for the source location backing a mount e.g. within `dbfs/mnt` then there is a way to do that using `dbutils.fs.mounts()`

For example this helper function will tell you the source of a dbfs mount:

```python
from typing import Optional
def get_dbfs_mnt_source(mount: str) -> Optional[str]:
  """gets the string path source for a dbfs mount point"""
  mnts = dbutils.fs.mounts()
  source = None
  for mnt in mnts:
    if mnt.mountPoint == mount:
      source = mnt.source
      break
  return source

#usage
s = get_dbfs_mnt_source('/mnt/s3-load-unload')
print(s)
```